# Cannot read property length of undefined, for array coming from resolver

Tags: angular

I have an array coming from a resolver.

```
private _fetchBieren: Bier[];
private _fetchBrouwers: Brouwer[];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(items => this._fetchBrouwers = items['brouwers']);
  this.route.data.subscribe(items => this._fetchBieren = items['mijnbieren']);
}

get mijnBieren$() {
  return this._fetchBieren;
}
```

When in my HTML I want to ask the length of this resolver I get an error

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I think this might be due to the fact that I resolve an observable and as I get it right, they don't have a length.

```
<div *ngIf="mijnBieren$.length > 0; else empty">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Naam</th>
     </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let bier of mijnbieren$">
          <td>{{bier.naam}}</td>
                  </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #empty>
  <div>Je lijst is leeg</div>
</ng-template>
```

I have already tried to use `mijnBieren?.length`, but this also returns an empty list even in cases when the list is not empty.

I expect to show the list when there are values, if there are not I want my template to be shown and say that the list is empty.

Comment: What is `mijnBieren$` that you have in your template? There's no sign of it in your TypeScript Class. Please share a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example as a part of your question so that it's easy to follow and help.

Comment: Excuse me, mijnBieren$ return this._fetchBieren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.route.data` yields data asynchronously, which is why you're subscribing to it in order to extract the data from it.

Here's what you can do:

```
public mijnbieren$: Observable<Bier[]>;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.mijnbieren$ = this.route.data.pipe(
    map(items => items['mijnbieren'])
  )
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="(mijnBieren$ | async as mijnBieren).length > 0; else empty">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Naam</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let bier of mijnbieren">
        <td>{{bier.naam}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<ng-template #empty>
  <div>Je lijst is leeg</div>
</ng-template>
```

Here we're not subscribing to the Observable. Instead we're mapping it to assign `mijnbieren` to a property `mijnbieren$`. We are then using the `async` pipe in the template to unwrap it.

Comment: Adjusting the ngIf to "(mijnbieren$ | async).length > 0; else empty
And the ngFor again an async, made it work. Thanks!